# Bind Specific Number of Columns of Dataset to Gridview

Tags: c#, data-binding, gridview, datasource, desktop-application

I am new to desktop application development.

I have a dataset which contains the following fields:

```
BillNo    |    Descirption    |  HSN Code    |   Qty    | Rate
```

and I have a grid view of type Data Grid View Text Box Column in which following columns are specified.

```
Sr No.    | Descirption     | HSN Code    |   Qty    | Rate    | Amount
```

I want to bind "Description","HSN Code","Qty" & "Rate" to the grid view from dataset  and I want to generate the "Sr No." & "Amount" programmatically of grid view.

How do I do this?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Create new Datatable object at run time and fill data table as per requirement and bind  it to datagrid or gridview

As shown below:

```
Private DataTable GetTable()
    {

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Sr No.", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Descirption", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
    .........
    ........


    retrive the data from datasourec in datatable dt

    //Here first loop through your orignal datatable or dataset

    forecch(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
    {
        table.Rows.Add("your sr no", drow["Descirption" ],drow["Code"]);     
    }
     return table;
    }
```

Comment: should I make the same name of column as grid view?
i.e. `table.Columns.Add("Sr No.", typeof(int));` and in grid view the column name is `clmSr` and header text is `Sr.` @raj

Comment: thanks it works perfectly.... But still one problem is there that it appends the columns to the existing grid view columns.. Data is not displayed in the existing columns What to do.?? @raj

Comment: Made the changes but still it appends the columns in grid. Not displaying at its actual position.@raj

Comment: Could you post your gridview markup code.it is hard to understand what you are saying.

Comment: or are you telling about the code for binding the data grid? @raj

Comment: sorry i was thinking asp.net gridview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27845/discussion-between-raj-and-riyaz-kalva)